# Cublic spline interpolation produces straight lines

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I would like to obtain a **smooth** curve going through specific points with integer coordinates. Instead of that I get straight line segments between the points. I tried `interp1d(x,y,kind='cubic')` and also `CubicSpline`, nothing works. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d,CubicSpline
x = np.arange(34)
y = [8,3,0,1,6,2,1,7,6,2,0,2,6,0,1,6,2,2,0,2,7,0,2,8,6,3,6,2,0,1,6,2,7,2]
f = CubicSpline(x, y)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

and here is the result:
[image]

Can you tell me how to get smooth curves instead?

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks! And sorry for the silly question. Could you rewrite your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you are using the original x-values to draw the curve. You need a new array with much more intermediate x-values. Numpy's `np.linspace()` creates such an array between a given minimum and maximum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, CubicSpline

y = [8, 3, 0, 1, 6, 2, 1, 7, 6, 2, 0, 2, 6, 0, 1, 6, 2, 2, 0, 2, 7, 0, 2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2, 7, 2]
x = np.arange(len(y))
f = CubicSpline(x, y)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
xs = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xs, f(xs))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing intermediate points to show an interpolating curve]